# Selection Sort - Functional Style with recursion

Tags: scala, functional-programming, selection-sort

Have only recently started learning Scala and am trying to delve into Functional Programming. I have seen many of the posts on Selection Sort Functional style; but am not totally been able to understand all the solutions that have been given. My Scala skills are still Nascent.

I have written a piece of Scala code using tail recursion and would appreciate any feedback on the style. Does it look like Functional Programming? Is there a way to make this better or make it more functional?

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

object FuncSelectionSort {
/**
* Selection Sort - Trying Functional Style
*/
def sort(a: Array[Int]) = {

    val b: Array[Int] = new Array[Int](a.size)
    Array.copy(a, 0, b, 0, a.size)

    // Function to swap elements
    def exchange(i: Int, j: Int): Unit = {
        val k = b(i);
        b(i) = b(j);
        b(j) = k;
    }

    @tailrec
    def helper(b: Array[Int], n: Int): Array[Int] = {
        if (n == b.length-1) return b
        else {
            val head = b(n);
            val minimumInTail = b.slice(n, b.length).min;

            if (head > minimumInTail) {
                val minimumInTailIndex = b.slice(n, b.length).indexOf(minimumInTail);
                exchange(n, minimumInTailIndex + n);
            }

            helper(b, n + 1)
        }
    }
    helper(b, 0)
    }
}
```

The logic that I have tried to adopt is fairly simple. I start with the first index of the Array and find the minimum from the rest. But instead of passing the Array.tail for the next recursion; I pass in the full array and check a slice, where each slice is one smaller than the previous recursion slice.

For example, 
If Array(10, 4, 6, 9, 3, 5)
First pass -> head = 10, slice = 4,6,9,3,5
First pass -> head = 4, slice = 6,9,3,5

I feel it looks the same as passing the tail, but I wanted to try and slice and see if it works the same way.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: This post is not containing programming problem, but rather a code review request. It's more appropriate at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, you are mutating the array, so it is by definition not "functional", or at least not "pure".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I understand what you mean by not functional; was new to functional and am still getting a hang of it.

Answer (score 4):

For detailed feedback on working code, you should better go to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/); however, I can say one thing: namely, in-place sorting arrays is per se not a good example of functional programming. This is because we purists don't like mutability, as it doesn't fit together well with recursion over data -- especially your mixing of recursion and mutation is not really good style, I'd say (and hard to read).

One clean variant would be to copy the full original array, and use in-place selection sort implemented as normal imperative code (with loops and in-place swap). Encapsulated in a function, this is pure to the outside. This pattern is commonly used in the standard library; cf. [List.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L1).

The other variant, and probably more instructive for learning immutable programming, is to use an immutable recursive algorithm over linked lists:

```
def sorted(a: List[Int]): List[Int] = a match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case xs => xs.min :: sorted(xs.diff(List(xs.min)))
}
```

From that style of programming, you'll learn much more about functional thinking (leaving aside efficiency though). Exercise: transform that code into tail-recursion.

(And actually, insertion sort works nicer with this pattern, since you don't have to "remove" at every step, but can build up a sorted linked list; you might try to implement that, too).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. :)